# Windows 10 Installation stuck at Manufacturer Boot Logo

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios, bsod, windows-installation

## Preface

Laptop started to BSOD (with DPC_WATCHDOG_VIOLATION) after installing a VM Hypervisor (Virtualbox/VMware Workstation) then the laptop started to load Windows Startup Repair and never proceeding beyond it. So attempting to clean reinstall Windows 10.

## Current State

Now when trying to reinstall Windows 10 using a USB installation media doesn't proceed beyond the boot logo screen and just keeps on loading.

## Attempted Solutions

1. Re-downloaded Windows ISO using WindowsMediaCreationTool.
2. Use a different pen drive to avoid any issues due to storage media.
3. Tried on different USB Ports to avoid port issues.
4. Restore BIOS to Factory Default.
5. Disable Fastboot in bios (No Off option available, only minimal and through options, switched it to minimal)

## Hardware

- Inspiron 15 Gaming 7566
- Core i5 6th Gen

Comment: If the hypervisor is the issue, you might turn off hypervisors (virtualization) in BIOS. If Windows then can be installed, try turning that feature back on.

Comment: Tried after disabling the virtualization in BIOS but it didn't work either. Later figured out that due to some other error in Dell BIOS it keeps going back to Windows installed bootloader in the SSD and not picking the bootloader of the Pen Drive. So I booted with a gparted live and then cleared the bootloader off the ssd. After that it worked.

Comment: Missaka, since you discovered the fix for that issue, you can answer your own question. Describe how you cleared the bootloader, and help others with that issue.